# Setting up a sliding character in the right way

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I would like to try and make a game similar to Altos Adventure. I am having trouble starting.

How to set up the terrain so that my character doesnt get stuck?

I simply drew a test sprite for the ground in photoshop. What collider2d should I use?
I use polygon collider and reduce friction in the material. But the character gets stuck, hits small invisible bumbs and it feels awful. The worst part is connecting 2 ground sprites together! The point where they connect is always messy.

I have a question for the future as well. How would I add the endless part of the game?
Would having many "pieces" set up and just spawning them as the player rides down work?

I havent written any code yet as the problem is simply in the physics in my opinion.

Thanks to anyone who takes the time and tries to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move your player use `rigid body.AddForce(Vector3 direction, ForceMode forceMode);` then create a Physics Material with `friction = 0` and put it in your player's collider.